# Custom control not usercontrol

Tags: .net, user-controls, devexpress

I want to make a (Devex) Ribbon-control with a few standard controls that I want to use on a lot of forms.
I used a usercontrol until now, but that makes a problem when merging in the main ribbon if its not a RibbonControl type.

How can that be done?

Comment: what development platform are you using?

Comment: You must be looking at Visual Inheritance http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/KB/p/A2912.aspx

Comment: Metro? WinForms? WPF? Silverlight? ASP.Net? MonoTouch?

Comment: @Saif Khan: Please add your comment as an answer so I could close this. Thanks you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be looking at [Visual Inheritance](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/KB/p/A2912.aspx)

You might also find this interesting [Does the XtraBars support Visual Form Inheritance?](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/kb/p/A1407.aspx)